# ionic 4 - how to animate toggling div

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm displaying a div conditionally

HTML

```
<div class="page_filters" [hidden]="!show_filters">
  my content
</div>
```

TS file

```
show_filters = false;

toggleFilters(){
  this.show_filters = !this.show_filters;
}
```

This works well, so I'm now trying to make it animated in a sliding way.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a class in content div  instead of `*ngIf` like

```
[class.opened]="show"
```

then apply the transition to that class

```
.opened {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: ease-in-out 600ms max-height;
}
```

Have a look at working example here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimum-angular-code-for-a-transition